# How do you filter out products from a productlist, based on 2 requirements?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to create a script that filters out products from a list of over 100.000 products. Requirements is to filter out unavailable products, and products from categories I do not wish to include.
I have 2 sheets, one with the product list, and another with the category list with true/false statements when they should be included.
My code so far looks like this:

```
  function deleteUnavailable() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var rss = ss.getSheetByName("Kategorier");
  var rRows = rss.getDataRange();
  var rNumRows = rRows.getNumRows();
  var rValues = rRows.getValues();

  var ass = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var aRows = ass.getDataRange();
  var aNumRows = aRows.getNumRows();
  var aValues = aRows.getValues();

  var resultArray = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= aNumRows -1; i++) {
    var keep = true;

    for (var j = 1; j <= rNumRows -1; j++) {

      if (aValues[i][3] == rValues[j][0]) {
        if (rValues[j][2] && aValues[i][9] == "JA") {break ;}
        else keep = false ; break ;
      }

    }
    if (keep) {
      resultArray.push(aValues[i]);
    }
  }
  ass.clear();
  ass.getRange(2, 1, resultArray.length, resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Trying to get this code:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= aNumRows -1; i++) {
    var keep = true;

    for (var j = 1; j <= rNumRows -1; j++) {

      if (aValues[i][3] == rValues[j][0]) {
        if (rValues[j][2] && aValues[i][9] == "JA") {break ;}
        else keep = false ; break ;
      }

    }
    if (keep) {
      resultArray.push(aValues[i]);
    }
  }
```

To copy the products and post them with this:

```
ass.clear();
ass.getRange(2, 1, resultArray.length, resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
```

Weirdly, using this code but with different placements work in my test sheets, but not in this one.
Can anyone tell me why this code leaves some products untouched when their conditions should be FALSE in my IF statement?

Comment: Javascript arrays are 0-base, yet you start at index 1. Also, `else keep = false; break;` is parsed as `else { keep = false; } break;`, which means as soon as `(aValues[i][3] == rValues[j][0])` is true, you stop your loop over `rValues` and move to the next `aValues` element.

Comment: I start the index at 1 to avoid the code removing the header row. I break the loop at that point as as soon as it finds a row that gives true, then no other row will give that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my code worked fine. There were just some inconsitancies with the information it was trying to work with, which lead the code to think everything was fine. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the indexing requirements, you can use some Array class methods'to make your logic more clear:

```js
  var rValues = rRows.getValues();
  var aValues = aRows.getValues();

// Create a pojo hash of information we should keep from rValues
// We care about matching the value in columns A (0) if C (2) is truthy.
const shouldKeep = rValues.slice(1) // skip the header row
  .reduce(function (hash, row) {
    if (row[2]) {
      // Column C is truthy, so store the value from column A
      hash[row[0]] = true;
    }
    return hash;
  }, {});

// Inspect all the data rows to see if the compare column D has a 
// value in the hash, and if so, that the other column J has the value "JA".
const rowsToKeep = aValues.slice(1)
  .filter(function (row) {
    return (
      // The tenth column must have the value "JA".
      row[9] === "JA"
        &&
      // The fourth column's value must be in our hash
      shouldKeep.hasOwnProperty(row[3])
    );
  });
// Do something with `rowsToKeep`
```

The above approach also removes a nested for loop, which should considerably improve script performance as the size of the rValues and aValues sheets grow, since you only loop rValues once, to construct the hash.